# Пошаговое руководство по установке Nodejs под Windows

Tags: node.js

привет.

К сожеленью не удалось найти руководство по установке сервера.

Кому не сложно раскажите самый простой вариант установки...

Comment: Скачайте установочный файл с http://nodejs.org/

Установите

cmd -> node text.js

Comment: файл создал //alert('1');document.write('aa');
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\1.js:2
document.write('aa');
^
ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: @zloctb так это и не браузер :D 

Вот лучше глянь, с чем он может работать: http://nodejs.org/api/

Comment: Спасибо.Это я уже узнал.Читаю книгу http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4212323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто!

1. Заходите на [сайт](http://www.ubuntu.com/)
2. Устанавливаете дистрибутив 2й стистемой или запускаете в VirtualBox
3. Делаете sudo apt-get install nodejs в терминале
4. Создаете файл test.js, в котором пишите console.log('hello something!')
5. Делаете node test.js
6. Смотрите результат!

Сугубо личное мнение, но если вы хотите изучать node и программирование в целом, лучше поставить что нибудь unix-подобное.

Comment: @MrFranke а в чем разница работы nodejs на windows и linux?

Я что-то не заметил пока.

Comment: Нет, сам nodejs работает одинаково) Дело в окружении, а именно в консоли винды. Мне показалась легче для восприятия консоль именно linux-a, по этому даже работая на винде я стараюсь работать с nodejs и прочими серверными технологиями на какомнибудь внешнем сервере с linux на борту, или в онлайн IDE типа cloud9

Comment: Если у пользователя венда, то ставить линух на виртуалку только из-за nodejs считаю глупым.

Comment: Если пользователь планирует и дальше развиваться в плане программирования, то лучше дома в спокойной обстановке познакомиться с линуксом, а не в панике гуглить на работе о том, что такое sudo и как установить рабочее окружение на сервере для работы над проектом. Но это, опять же, ИМХО. Но ради одного nodejs поднимать виртуалку конечно же глупо

Answer (score 3):

Скачиваете дистрибутив с [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/) и запускаете его. NodeJS установлен!

Comment: Установил.Теперь мне после апача непрывычно....Где localhost...как писать сайт....?Надеюсь все это узнаю с книги.

Comment: @zloctb тут немного по другому всё организовано. Грубо говоря, сначала нужно написать сам веб-сервер (который вещает в интернет, также, как и апач), дальше самому сделать роутинг запросов. Т.е. идет запрос /node/dir/ в ноду просто приходит строка. Дальше с этой строкой ты можешь делать всё, что угодно.

Вот тебе пример веб-сервера

    var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello World\n');
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

\

Comment: Спасибо lampa....